# Laravel is producing error from regex input

Tags: regex, laravel, validation

I want to pass in string but it is proucing a error. This is what I wrote

```
'level'=>'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/'
```

This is producing error invalid format. I do not know what could be wrong.

Any help would be appreciated

**update**

My input could like

1. Software engineer 1
2. S.E. 1
3. Software engineer etc

But it is still giving the error

Comment: Share your error log.

Comment: you're getting a validation error right? so please share your input values and tell what exactly you are validating?

Comment: @OsamaAlvi response given

Comment: @AlimonKarim error log? in the command line there is no error. it is showing it in the form and I have set the form to recieve error generated from the backend

Comment: @S Mev try this:regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\. ]*$/    there is space after dot

Comment: @OsamaAlvi I will try t and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @OsamaAlvi I am very grateful. it worked, What could have been the reason for that

Comment: @S Mev your input contains spaces and you were not validating it.